# What is the correct way to pass a struct to a function?

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct, which i'd like to pass to a function. Obviousley i am making somethin wrong, since the output is always the same : `(null)`

Could someone please help me. 
Thanks!

```
typedef struct
{
    char * Value1;
    char * Value2;
} TESTSTRUCT, *PTESTSTRUCT;

BOOL MyFunction(PTESTSTRUCT TestStruct);
BOOL QueryData(char * String, char * Name);

int main ()
{
   TESTSTRUCT myStruct;
   ZeroMemory( &myStruct, sizeof( myStruct) );

   MyFunction( &myStruct );

   printf( "\nmyStruct.Value1    = %s", myStruct.Value1);
   printf( "\nmyStruct.Value2    = %s", myStruct.Value2 );
   if ( myStruct.Value1 != NULL ) LocalFree( myStruct.Value1);
   if ( myStruct.Value2 != NULL ) LocalFree( myStruct.Value2 );
}
BOOL MyFunction(PTESTSTRUCT TestStruct)
{
   //.....
   QueryData(TestStruct->Value1, TestStruct->Value2);
   //.....
}
QueryData(char * String, char * Name)
{
    // do some stuff
    LPTSTR szName = NULL;
    szName = ( LPTSTR )LocalAlloc( LPTR, dwData * sizeof( TCHAR ) );
    String = AllocateMemory(szName);
    LocalFree( szName );
    szName = NULL;
    // do some more work
    szName = ( LPTSTR )LocalAlloc( LPTR, dwData * sizeof( TCHAR ) );
    Name = AllocateMemory(szName);
    LocalFree( szName );
}
LPSTR AllocateMemory( LPSTR inputString )
{
LPSTR outputString = NULL;

outputString = ( LPSTR )LocalAlloc( LPTR, ( strlen( inputString ) + 1 ) * sizeof( CHAR ) );

if (outputString != NULL)
{
    lstrcpyA( outputString, inputString );
}

return outputString;
}
```

Comment: This `BOOL` thing hurts my eyes. Why is there a "windows" tag, does your question have to do with the OS of your machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you assign to the pointer in `QueryData`. Since C passes all arguments by value, the pointer is copied, and you only modify the local copy inside the `QueryData` function.

You need to emulate pass by reference (I say "emulate" because C doesn't have pass by reference), by passing a pointer, in your case passing a pointer to the pointer.

Something like:

```
BOOL QueryData(char ** String, char ** Name)
{
    ...
    *String = AllocateMemory(...);
    ...
    *Name = AllocateMemory(...)
    ...
}
```

Call it like

```
QueryData(&TestStruct->Value1, &TestStruct->Value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers in C are passed by value:  the `String` and `Name` arguments in `QueryData` are local variables that are initially *copies* of the (null) pointers in the caller's `TestStruct`.  Changing the local variables within `QueryData` does not change the values stored in the structure.

You need to pass `QueryData` either a pointer to the structure itself  (i.e. `QueryData(TestStruct)`) or pointers to the two `char*` values stored within the structure (i.e. `QueryData(&TestStruct->Value1, &TestStruct->Value2)`), so that `QueryData` can change the contents of the structure itself.